# In VS2010, use openMP firstprivate failed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing, openmp

Code

```
double t;
double limit = 10;
double result = 1000;
int i;

#pragma omp parallel sections default(none) firstprivate(result) lastprivate(result) private(t) shared(limit)
{ 
    #pragma omp section
    {
        printf("Section1: result = %f\n", result);
        result += 55;
        printf("Section1: result = %f\n", result);
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
        printf("Section2: result = %f\n", result);
        result += 3628800;
        printf("Section2: result = %f\n", result);
    }
}
printf("result1 = %0.0lf\n", result);
```

The result is

```
Section1: result = 1000.000000
Section1: result = 1055.000000
Section2: result = 1000.000000
Section2: result = 3629800.000000
result1 = 3629800
```

OR

```
Section1: result = 1000.000000
Section1: result = 1055.000000
Section2: result = 1055.000000
Section2: result = 3629855.000000
result1 = 3629855
```

In VS2010, I use the firstprivate to initialize the `result` in section.
I think that, in section1 or section 2, the result should be 1000 before the operation `+`

However, the result may be initialized to 1055 in section 2 when I run the program.
Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the OpenMP standard which guarantees that sections are to be executed by different threads. MSVC's OpenMP runtime assigns sections dynamically, i.e. once a thread becomes ready, it is assigned the next section in the queue. In this scenario it is possible that the other threads are still being created at the moment when the master thread has finished executing the first section. What will happen is that the master thread will start executing the second section. Exactly that scenario is shown in the example which accompanies the description of `sections` in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k4b1177.aspx). Since the `(first|last)private` clauses apply per thread and not per section, `result` will have an initial value of `1055.0` in the second section.

You can easily see how it happens:

```c
#pragma omp section
{
    printf("Section1: thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    printf("Section1: result = %f\n", result);
    result += 55;
    printf("Section1: result = %f\n", result);
}
#pragma omp section
{
    printf("Section2: thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    printf("Section2: result = %f\n", result);
    result += 3628800;
    printf("Section2: result = %f\n", result);
}
```

Now check if the thread ID is the same for both sections when the second sample output from your question is realised and if the they differ when the first output is realised.

OpenMP sections are supposed to be independent. In your case there is a data dependence between the two sections carried by the `result` variable.